# Restart sequence for multi node data center

Tags: cassandra

We are using Cassandra version : 3.11.2 and We have two data centers A and B both have 3 nodes each , while seeds i have mentioned as 1st ip of DC A and 1 ip of DC B in all 6 nodes in cassandra.yml.

Now for maintenance for patching on DC B nodes, where we need to stop cassandra on DC B nodes and restart it..

My confusion is:

- Whether restart of DC B affects DC A nodes and its data replication ?

Restart doubts:

- Can I stop only on DC B nodes and restart (starting with seed node and then non seed). Is this correct method of restart ?
  or
- As seed nodes are from both DC's, do I need to stop all nodes on both DC starting with seed nodes after maintenance on DC B ?

I am asking these question in light of scenario node failure or data loss..

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `hinted_handoff_enabled` enabled (by default) and your maintenance is inside `max_hint_window_in_ms` time frame (3 hours), then after restart of `DC B` the data will be streamed from nodes in `DC A`, so eventually you get all data into `DC B` as well.  To make sure, you can [perform repair](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/repair.html) after all nodes are back.

Regarding restart:

- It's better to start seed node in `DC B` first, but you need to make sure that seed node in `DC A` is online at that moment;
- You don't need to stop all nodes of cluster before restart of one DC;
- in `DC B` you can even patch your nodes one by one, and restart them separately, but this may depend on what kind of patching you're doing, like, is it Cassandra upgrade, or something like. In this case you may need to disable repairs, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex much appreciated for answer. I shall check those values.. is that max_hint_window_in_ms available in cassandra.yaml ? Anyway I will verify now. Regarding patch it's is upgraded from them 7.4 to 7.5 via yum update. Nothing related to Cassandra...

Comment: If it's just OS upgrade, then just patch one node a time and restart. Before stopping Cassandra explicitly call `nodetool drain`

Comment: Thank you for help. All went smooth.